# Matchmaking with socket.io - rely on setInterval or socket calls?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, setinterval, matchmaking

I'm developing a game where my backend is written in NodeJS and I use socket.io for realtime communication.

One of the features of my game is matchmaking. Basically, if more than two players are on matchmaking period, my application will create a game room (special socket.io room) for them and start the game.

There are two ways to do this:

- Create a setInterval on NodeJS. In the interval, check playersInMatchmaking array. If there are more than 2 players in the array, create the game room. I will loop as long as the server is online.
- Instead of relying on setInterval, check playersInMatchmaking array each time I receive a call to `socket.on("matchmaking start")` or `socket.on("matchmaking stop")`

Is there any benefits of using certain approach? setInterval sounds easier as I can decouple matchmaking algorithm from socket logic, however it will be less performant as matchmaking algorithm will run in a loop as opposed to socket events.

What do you think? Do you have any other ideas that would work better?

Answer (score 2):

You will maximize the utilisation of socket.io and real-time communication by using events. If there is no other reason other than decoupling the algorithm, you should use events. There are no reason to run the loop over and over again if there are currently no users/players participating or searching for the match.

If the interval is not small enough (for example 5 seconds), I would also consider what happens when Player1 is put into queue, Player2 also comes in the queue, and in between 2 intervals Player1 cancels his search for opponent since he's tired of waiting. So main benefit of event triggered systems other than the one you mentioned (performance) is that there is no real delay (except the network, code looping, jitter, ..) and things happen immediately